# how to remove whitespace in text field

Tags: mysql, field, trim

My database consists of 5 fields

```sql
CREATE TABLE books(
    _id integer primary key autoincrement,
    name text not null,
    amount text,
    bookdetails text,
    timeperiod text
);
```

I have some whitespace at the end of a each paragraph in bookdetails text field. I used select rtrim(bookdetails) from books; command to remove the whitespace but it didnt worked.

I want to remove all the whitespace after "bookdetails" field text of all columns of the table.

Answer (score 0):

The Trim function only removes regular spaces and not other whitespace characters,
try with:

```
TRIM(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(bookdetails,'\t',''),'\f',''),'\n',''),'\r','')‌​)
```